# commercial access points

Tags: wifi, access-point

What are some of the popular commercial access points which I can plug righ into my network? I am running all sonicwall devices. I am aware that sonicwall has a AP, however, I am trying to avoid their licensing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Cisco Aironet for use where a "consumer" grade unit isn't acceptable.

Comment: The Cisco Aironet gear is a bit pricey, but it's great gear. It's very reliable and has a good feature-set.

Comment: Are there easy to configure? I'd purchased one a while back but later found out it was depenant on a parent device to be installed on the network. Is there a model I can plug rignt into my network and configure?

Comment: Yes.  We use the Cisco Aironet 1100 (maybe a newer model since we last bought one).  It's standalone and works fine without any other devices.

Comment: When you order the Aironet AP,  They sell two verions of most models,  one for use with a Controller, and one as a standalone.  It is supposedly possible to flash the firmware on one to change to the other, but I never did it.  The one time a vendor sold me the wrong version, I just exchanged it for the standalone version.  The Standalone verisons generally configure through a Web interface, much like the consumer models.

Comment: As BillN mentions *don't* buy the "lightweight" version, it's not just a flash change to get the full firmware these days, Cisco will want another few hundred dollars first.

Comment: Get an AP with IOS.  Don't get the LWAPP.  I believe you can get an IOS AP to work like an LWAPP later if needed but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

We implemented [Aerohive](http://www.aerohive.com/). Specifically because it met each of our requirements, a.) ultimately manageable by the helpdesk, b.) reliable security, and c.) good support.

(Personally however, I would have opted for a Cisco wireless AP solution, but that's just me. :)

Answer (score 2):

At my office we use [Ruckus](http://www.ruckuswireless.com/) gear. The thing I really like about the ruckus is the management box. It makes administrating/updating all of our APs all too easy.
Colleague of mine does town/city wide wireless networks and uses [Aruba](http://www.arubanetworks.com/index.en.php)

::Edit:: I just re-read your question, you wanted something that is "plug-n-play" into your existing network. The Aruba is way over what you need, but the ruckus might work.

Answer (score 1):

Is the SonicWall licensing required just for updates?  Going with Cisco would require a SmartNet agreement for software and support.  You might want to consider moving to HP gear.  Their support is incredible and the price is reasonable.

Comment: SonicWalls are a PITA in general.  The licensing is required for everything, not just updates.

Comment: seriously, it's one of the things I dislike about sonicwall.

Answer (score 1):

Colubris AP by HP. You can also get A controller which once you plug in the AP's they get a default config.  The APs are dual radio and draft N as well as ABG. HP do lifetime* warranty too. By * I am not sure what the exact definition of lifetime warranty.